# "One track mind"; what is it supposed to be?

Tags: idioms, questions, word-difference

I'm doing some exercises online, I have to deal with [this question](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic3785.html#meaning_of_one_track_mind).

> He has a one ......... mind as all he ever talks about is money, money, money.
>
> (a) track
> (b) road
> (c) path
> (d) rail

How am I going to be able to decide which option to choose? Is the answer a set idiom or can it be different in other circumstances?

thank you for your help

Comment: Have you checked thesaurus dictionaries?

Comment: @MARamezani Yes I did. But in [some examples](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic3785.html#meaning_of_one_track_mind) I don't know how to choose between them.

Comment: Gianni, I did an edit to your question so that it becomes acceptable in here. Please avoid asking Qs in a way that seem answerable with a dictionary.

Comment: @TRomano's answer is comprehensive. The options in your question are really random in my idea.

Comment: @MARamezani thanks for your help, now it is more clear. If the options are really random, the right answers come up only as idiomatic expression. I need to know the expression, the meaning is hardly enough to get the right one, right?

Comment: Right. The question's intention is only the idiom behind the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A person whose thoughts always turn to a particular subject  (e.g. sex, money, football, whatever)  regardless of the current topic of conversation is said (colloquially) to have a "one-track mind".

A person who finds a sexual *double entendre* in nearly everything people say could be said to have a one-track mind. Austin Powers has a one-track mind. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Idiomatic meanings can be hard to find in a dictionary. Sometimes they are listed under one of the main words, sometimes they are listed as a full and separate entry.

For example, if you look up *mind* in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mind?showCookiePolicy=true), you'll see idioms such as:

- *blow someone's mind*
- *give someone a piece of one's mind*
- *make up one's mind*

and if you look up *track*, you'll find:

- *the right track*
- *the wrong track*
- *off the beaten track*

In Collins, though, *one-track mind* is not listed – probably because [*one-track* gets its own entry](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/one-track).

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/one-track-mind) lists it slightly differently, though; it has an entry for *one-track mind*.

Sometimes you'll find the meaning of the idiom within the definition of one of its key words; other times you'll find the idiom listed by itself. In the case of a test question, when you don't know what the right answer is, you might have to try several possibilities before you stumble across the right one.

OneLook is an especially good on-line resource for this, because it searches several dictionaries for a word or phrase. For example, when I enter [one road mind](http://www.onelook.com/?w=one%20road%20mind&ls=a) into OneLook, it apologizes and informs me that no matches were found, but when I enter [one track mind](http://www.onelook.com/?w=one%20track%20mind&ls=a), it finds matches in four dictionaries.