# What does “with a one track mind” mean in Queen's I Want It All?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, lyrics

In the song *I Want It All* by *Queen*, there are these lyrics:

> I'm a man with a one track mind
>   So much to do in one lifetime (people do you hear me?)
>   Not a man for compromise and 'wheres' and 'whys' and living lies
>   So I'm living it all (yes I'm living it all)
>   And I'm giving it all (and I'm giving it all)

By dictionary, "one track mind" means "having only one interest/think about only one topic". But here he said he wanted to do so much in life. This is kind of contradictory.

What does it mean here? And if there is contradiction, what is the meaning of the whole passage?

Comment: You have already asked this question here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452704/what-does-with-a-one-track-mind-mean-in-queens-i-want-it-all  You should not be asking it again at this site.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, I asked there, and some users suggest asking on this site. Is it also not suitable for ELL?

Comment: It might belong here—but the original question should be migrated here instead. I will see what I can do.

Comment: related: [“One track mind”; what is it supposed to be?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47523/one-track-mind-what-is-it-supposed-to-be)

Comment: He does have a one track mind; he is obsessed with being rich and successful. He may have to do many different things to obtain this, but all of these actions lead to the same ultimate goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of the song:

> I'm a man with a **one track mind**
>   **So much to do** in one lifetime

The "*one track mind*" refers to his wanting it *all*, that is all (*the only thing*) he can think about. The speaker is **single-minded**, determined and, in this case, extremely focused. In another sense, he is very much aware that life is brief, which means he **doesn't want to** ***[miss out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/miss-out)*** **on** anything, he wants to experience everything that life offers him, and the sooner the better “‘I want it all, and I want it now”.

Without context:

> a man with a ***[one-track mind](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-track-mind)***

is usually used as a euphemism for a man (in this case) whose only thought and interest (fixation) is sex.

- *And no, Bill, I wasn't talking about sex - you have a one-track mind!*

Origin:

The “one track” alludes to the single-track railway or to a train that that runs in only one direction. First recorded in 1928 ([source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/one-track-mind))

[image]

Comment: In the song, does "one track mind" also mean he is determined, related to "not a man for compromise". Also what is the meaning of "and 'wheres' and 'whys'"? Thanks

Comment: @THN Only one question at a time and one only. Choose wisely

Comment: OK, I choose this: In the song, does "one track mind" also mean he is determined, related to "not a man for compromise", it's detail of the original question. To understand the whole passage here, there are more questions needed though.

Comment: @THN  First of all, it's a song and more often than not words are chosen for their rhyme, and metre.  In response to your 2nd question, yes, you're right. In this song the "one track mind" is similar to being **single-minded**, determined and, in this case, extremely focused. He is ambitious *and* very impatient.

Comment: Thanks, I see, extended discussion makes me understand it better. Unfortunately place for discussion is very limited.

Comment: @THN you can ask a new question about "where's and why's" I don't think it has been asked before, and this construction is frequently used in English. Similar to the [**"do's and dont's"**](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=a4g4W-KzE8LYsQWfzbnYAw&q=%22Do%27s+and+don%27ts%22&oq=%22Do%27s+and+don%27ts%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0l10.13923.16159.0.18197.2.2.0.0.0.0.135.270.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.269...0i10k1.0.2QAg8t15Llg) lists that infest the Internet. I think it would make a very good, and interesting question. Just show evidence that you used a dictionary before posting.